# How to solve triangle side length with unknown variable?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

How do I solve this problem? I think it has to do with sinus, but I'm not sure. I'm quite new to this area so I would appreciate a detailed explanation. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You can use the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), which establishes a relationship between the lengths of the sides and one of the angles. That gives you an equation (a quadratic equation) from where you can solve for possible values of $y$. The equation in question will be $(4.5+y)^2=(4.5)^2+(9-y)^2-2\cdot(4.5)\cdot(9-y)\cdot\cos(70)$.

Comment: Great, thank you! @Quarantino

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that does not use the cosine's law but an observation : whatever $y$, we have

$$CA+CB=13.5$$

[image]

Therefore, $C$ belongs to the ellipse with foci $A$ and $B$ and parameters $2a=13.5$ and interfocal distance $2f=4.5$ giving :

$$b^2=a^2-f^2=81/2$$

Taking (see figure) coordinate axes such that $A(-2.25 ; 0)$ and $B(2.25 ; 0)$, we get the following equation :

$$\dfrac{x^2}{(27/4)^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{(81/2)}=1 \tag{1}$$

Besides, straight line passing through $A$ with a $70°$ slope angle has equation

$$y=\tan(70°)(x+2.25).$$

It suffices now to find the intersection point of this ellipse and the straight line.

We find the point $C$ with coordinates

$$(x_0= 0.066181051712292,\ \ y_0=6.363655138948179)$$

Now, one must take care : the value of $y_0$ found here isn't the same as the looked for $y$. One has to solve $9-y=CA=\sqrt{(x_0+2.25)^2+(y_0-0)^2}$ finally giving :

$$\color{red}{y=2.227939649429236}$$

**Remark** : This method is not the shortest ; its interest is that it brings a better understanding of the issue, especially in connection with the value of the angle which can be taken in the whole range $(0,180°)$.

Comment: y is actually about 2.228

Comment: Yes, there is confusion between two meanings of $y$. I am going to correct it.

Comment: There was as well a problem with the $a$ and $b$ lengths I have fixed now.

Comment: great thank you